# SQL Query to take top 1 row from one table and put it as column field in another

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to take the first row from the product table that matches the category ID and put that value into the category tables meta description field, at the moment it puts the last record into the field, but I need the first record which is the best seller.

The code I am attempting to use is below, I have been up late and I am tired, if a magic fairy can come and help me solve this I will send you 100 Karma points.

```
 UPDATE Category 
SET
    MetaTitle  = Name + ' Audio Books',
    MetaKeywords = Name + ' ,audio books, download, free, audio book, online, audio book, audiobooks, audiobook, mp3 books, cd, free trial, spoken, spoken word, talking, talking books',
    MetaDescription = 'Our best sellers in audio books for ' + Name + ' which includes ' + pname

    FROM
    (
    SELECT TOP 1
        p.Name as pname,
        pcm.CategoryId as pCat,
        p.CreatedOnUtc 
    FROM 
        Product p
    INNER JOIN 
        Product_Category_Mapping pcm
    ON 
        p.Id = pcm.ProductId
    ORDER BY 
        CreatedOnUtc DESC
    ) newproduct 
WHERE
    Category.Id = newproduct.pCat 
and Category.Id >=22
and ParentCategoryId <> 0
```

ps: created on desc will show the record I want.

Comment: A shot in the dark here, so if `ORDER BY CreatedOnUtc DESC` gives you the last record, wouldn't it follow that `ORDER BY CreatedOnUtc ASC` would return the first?

Comment: The clause us correct, i need to put it at end of query also, but it does not like a order by for some reason, any ideas?

Comment: well yes, you cannot use an `order by` in a subquery. So you may have to break apart the `UPDATE` statement from the subquery to obtain the data you need for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query inside the FROM () will only get the single newest Product (in all categories). So it will only update that whatever category that product is in.

You need to get to get the top product for every category. Try this:

```
UPDATE Category
SET
    MetaTitle = Name + ' Audio Books',
    MetaKeywords = Name + ' ,audio books, download, free, audio book, online, audio book, audiobooks, audiobook, mp3 books, cd, free trial, spoken, spoken word, talking, talking books',
    MetaDescription = 'Our best sellers in audio books for ' + Name + ' which includes ' + pname
FROM
(
     SELECT
        p.Name AS pname,
        pcm.CategoryId AS pCat,
        p.CreatedOnUtc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY pcm.CategoryId 
            ORDER BY CreatedOnUtc DESC
        ) AS RowNumber
     FROM Product p
     INNER JOIN Product_Category_Mapping pcm
        ON p.Id = pcm.ProductId
) newproduct
WHERE
    newproduct.RowNumber = 1
    AND Category.Id = newproduct.pCat 
    AND Category.Id >=22
    AND ParentCategoryId <> 0
```

Comment: Thank you Ben, a nice present to wake up to, I hope you have a great day and also thanks fnostro. :-)